# Implementar una cola en JAVA error al quitar el segundo elemento

Tags: java

Estoy implementando una cola en JAVA de manera muy simple, cuando funcione le agregaré las excepciones. Por un lado tengo la clase Nodo que sería el elemento:

```
public class Nodo {
private int dato;
private Nodo siguiente; ...
```

Y en la clase Cola, lo siguiente:

```
public class cola {

private Nodo ultimo;
private Nodo primero;
private int cant;

public cola() {
    this.ultimo = null;
    this.primero = null;
    this.cant = 0;
}

public void agregar(int dato) {
    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(dato, null);
    if (cant == 0) {
        primero = nuevo;
        ultimo = nuevo;
    }
    if (cant == 1) {
        ultimo = nuevo;
        primero.setSiguiente(nuevo);
    } else {
        ultimo = nuevo;
        //ultimo.setSiguiente(nuevo);
    }
    cant = cant + 1;
}

public void quitar() {
    Nodo aux;
    aux = primero.getSiguiente();
    primero = null;
    primero = aux;
    cant = cant - 1;

}
```

Ya en la clase principal, creo el objeto agrego elementos y funciona bien, quito el primer elemento y también pero al querer quitar un segundo elemento me salta el error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at Principal.main(Principal.java:26)
> C:\Users\carmigh\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
> .

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    cola cola1= new cola();
    cola1.agregar(10);
    cola1.agregar(5);
    cola1.agregar(15);
    cola1.agregar(25);
    cola1.agregar(35);
    cola1.quitar();
    cola1.agregar(10);
    cola1.quitar();
    System.out.println("Primero: "+cola1.getPrimero().getDato()+ " Último: "+cola1.getUltimo().getDato()+" Cantidad de elementos: "+cola1.getCant());
}
```

Omití pegar los setter y getter pero en las clases en que estoy implementando el ejercicio están!
Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar! Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El problema que yo veo es en tu método de ingresar nodos a la cola.

```
public void agregar(int dato) {
    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(dato, null);
    if (cant == 0) {
        primero = nuevo;
        ultimo = nuevo;
    }
    if (cant == 1) {
        ultimo = nuevo;
        primero.setSiguiente(nuevo);
    } else {
        // en este caso es cuando estas perdiendo la relación.
        ultimo = nuevo;
        //ultimo.setSiguiente(nuevo); 
    }
    cant = cant + 1;
}
```

Puedes intentar con este bloque de código:

```
public void agregar(int dato) {
    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(dato, null);
    if (cant == 0) {
        primero = nuevo;
        ultimo = nuevo;
    }else
    {
        ultimo.setSiguiente(nuevo); 
        // Del ultimo nodo, asignas el puntero al nuevo nodo
        // Despues actualizas tu variable ultimo
        ultimo = nuevo;
    }
    cant = cant + 1;
}
```

Israel Ramos

Comment: Claro, lo estaba haciendo en orden inverso y sobreescribia la variable... Ahora sí funciona! Muchas gracias Israel!

Comment: @carmigh si te fue de ayuda marca la respuesta como aceptada dando clic en el check.